# reflector and importing resources

Tags: c#, .net

I am using reflector to disassemble on of my companys projects so that one of our departments can speak to our headquarters in germany intellegently. I have successfully completeted my task other than the following issue.

whenever a resource image or anything referring to the manager

```
ComponentResourceManager manager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(PalletPlacesUserControl));
```

is executed

```
this.cmdSpreading.Image = (Image) manager.GetObject("cmdSpreading.Image");
```

i end up with an error because manager is null.

Comment: You need Reflector to debug your *own* projects?  Are you sure that's legal?

Comment: Exactly.. its a long story but we are owned ultimately by germany who likes to hide information about things to us (U.S) but i was asked by a different department to help with this to open the information chains while the legalitity is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Red Gate's .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), you can call a file-save as C# project, and that builds a Visual Studio project that will compile and run (if it is an executable) just like the normal code would, plus you can edit the code there. I would try that first and see what happens.

Comment: thats what im using, maybe its the disassembler tool that i used with it?

Comment: Try right clicking on the assembly, and choose export. Then open project up and see what it looks like.

Comment: that isnt making a difference. The problem i think is because my resourceCulture is null

Comment: Well that would be a problem, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager
        {
            get
            {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null))
                {
                    System.Resources.ResourceManager manager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Logistics.Products.LayerPicking.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = manager;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

Comment: that is the code for the section of getting the resources. Ive just never done anything like this with resources before. Most of my experience is much simplier than this.

Comment: Ya me too... try changing the line `if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null))` to `if (resourceMan == null)`

Comment: same results, it just passes through as at that poiont resourceMan is allready null

Comment: I dont know then... sorry that I couldn't help you, I would try asking again or waiting another day and putting a bounty on this question...